# Elastic Search Azure Plugin Issue

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, azure-elastic-scale

The elastic search azure plugin troubleshooting issue:

I am trying to snapshot the index data from on prem to azure and am getting the same exception:

```
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "repository_verification_exception",
                "reason": "[qarepository] path  is not accessible on master node"
            }
        ],
        "type": "repository_verification_exception",
        "reason": "[qarepository] path  is not accessible on master node",
        "caused_by": {
            "type": "i_o_exception",
            "reason": "Can not write blob master.dat",
            "caused_by": {
                "type": "storage_exception",
                "reason": "storage_exception: ",
                "caused_by": {
                    "type": "i_o_exception",
                    "reason": "qaonpremesindex.blob.core.windows.net"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "status": 500
}

steps followed:
Created storage account in azure
Created a blob container
added the keystore values(name&key)

PUT _snapshot/qarepository
{
    "type": "azure"

}
```